# strcmp() returns 10 when I compare the exact same string in C

Tags: c, string, equality, strcmp

I am building a basic shell program, and and using a while loop to continually prompt the user and they can put in commands to run. When the user inputs 'exit' I want my shell program to terminate. I use fgets to get the user input, and parse it out into an array `cmdArr` using strtok.

```
int j = 0;
char **cmdArr;
char inputsp[128];
char *cmds;

printf("==>");
fgets(inputs, 128, stdin);
cmds = strtok(inputs, " ");
while (j<1) {

    i = 0;
    while (cmds != NULL) {
        cmdArr[i] = cmds;
        cmds = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    if (strcmp(cmdArr[0], "exit") == 0) {
        printf("exit command passed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        printf("==>");
        fgets(inputs, 128, stdin);
        cmds = strtok(inputs, " ");
   }
}
```

When I type in exit, I have confirmed that cmdArr[0] stores the string "exit" by `printf`ing cmdArr[0]. When I print out the value of `strcmp(cmdArr[0], "exit")` I always get the value as 10, and I'm nore entirely sure why. I believe they are the same two string, so `strcmp` should be returning 0 correct?

Comment: 10 is the ASCII code for a newline character, so one of your strings has a newline at the end, and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

`fgets` does not remove the newline from strings it reads, even if it's reading from `stdin`. The return value of `strcmp` is the difference between the strings at the first place they differ, namely, the newline, which has the ASCII value `10`.

Comment: That's a common implementation of `strcmp` but the standard doesn't specify it and it is unwise to rely on it. You can count on the sign of the return value: if its zero the strings are equal, if negative the first string comes first in lexicographic order, and if positive, the second string comes first.

Comment: @rici I was describing the behavior that was being exhibited on the OP's system - but you are right.